# What was the nature of the Backbone collection sync event?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone.js-collections

If one set's a event listeners on a Backbone collection's sync event, how can it be determined from the event listener what the nature of the sync was: was it an updated? a new model was added to the collection or was actually deleted?

At the fist glance the information about the completed xhr request that is being returned to the listener does not contain the HTTP method used with that sync (get, put, post or delete).

Comment: Can you override the `sync()` method for the collection instead of triggering on the completion event? If so, the `method` parameter will tell you the type of sync required.

Comment: I will look into that... It's kind of silly that that is what is required to get the sync type. Initially I assumed there's something I was missing but after the silence this question is facing I assume it's not the case.

Comment: @StephenThomas - I ended up using the sync method override after all; if you move you comment into an answer I can set that as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the sync() method for the collection instead of triggering on the completion event. If that's doable, the `method`parameter will tell you the type of sync required.